# rails c not using the same database as rails db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I just realized that when I run `rails c` I'm getting a different database than when I run `rails db`.

I initially though the console wasn't connecting to the database at all because it kept returning empty sets, for instance when running `User.all`, despite having seed data. I then inserted data into the database via the console and did a query from the SQLite console. The new data did not appear even after reloading the console.

My confusion is further exacerbated by the fact that I only have the `db/development.sqlite3` file and `rails r "puts Rails.env"` returns `Development`.

So where might I have gone wrong here? Why is one using the development database and the other seemingly using something else? Could `rake db:seed` be pushing to `Test` perhaps? Is there a way to check the SQLite console for the environment?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `Spring` was causing the problem. I had a previous app with the same name and it was loading that when I opened the rails console despite being in the newer app directory.

I've disabled `Spring` with the `DISABLE_SPRING` variable and now things are working as expected.

Comment: Having the same issue. Save me about 30mins. Thanks